# i am not able to find order through id in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, transform, shopping-cart

I am new to shopping cart. I am able to get all the data from order table on this page but i am not able to find single order by ID:
This is my view page where i am sending the $id to the controller of the order.
id)}}">Order# {{$order->id}}
The whole code:
'''

@foreach($orders as $order)
@if($order->status == "CompletedOrders")

```
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="list-group" >

                                <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #5C94ED">
                                    <a href="{{route('showcompleteorder',$order->id)}}"><h1 style="color: #FBEB58">Order# {{$order->id}}</h1></a>
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Name: {{$order->name}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Phone: {{$order->phone}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    @foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
                                        <span class="badge" style="color: #FBEB58; font-size: 16px">{{$item['qty'] }} {{ $item['item']['name'] }}</span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="badge" style="color: #FBEB58; font-size: 16px">Price: ${{ $item['price'] }}</span>
                                        <br>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Instructions: {{$order->table}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Time: {{$order->created_at}}</span>
                                    <br>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <strong style="color: #222D32; font-size: 18px">Total Price: ${{ $order->cart->totalPrice }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div" />
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

'''
This is my route

'''

```
Route::get('showcompleteorder/{id}','OrderController@showCompleteOrder')->name('showcompleteorder');
```

'''
and this is my controller:

```
public function showCompleteOrder($id){
    $orders = Order::find($id);
    $orders->transform(function ($order, $key) {
        $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
        return $order;
    });
    return view('orders.showcompleteorders', ['orders' => $orders]);

}
```

but when i run this. it gives me a error of transform:

```
BadMethodCallException
```

Call to undefined method App\Order::transform()
http://localhost:8000/showcompleteorder/2

This is my view where i am trying to get the order by id:

```
 @foreach($orders as $order)
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="list-group" >

                                <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #5C94ED">
                                    <h1 style="color: #FBEB58">Order# {{$order->id}}</h1>
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Name: {{$order->name}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Phone: {{$order->phone}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    @foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
                                        <span class="badge" style="color: #FBEB58; font-size: 16px">{{$item['qty'] }} {{ $item['item']['name'] }}</span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="badge" style="color: #FBEB58; font-size: 16px">Price: ${{ $item['price'] }}</span>
                                        <br>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Instructions: {{$order->table}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: black; font-size: 16px">Time: {{$order->created_at}}</span>
                                    <br>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <strong style="color: #222D32; font-size: 18px">Total Price: ${{ $order->cart->totalPrice }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            @endforeach
```

Can Someone please help me

Comment: Your problem is on your transform method, change `$orders = Order::find($id);` to `$orders = Order::where('id', $id)->get();`

Comment: I solved it. My problem was that i was not able to get specific order. So i sent id from order blade to controller and used a variable to be equal to that id. and then i sent that variable to my front blade again where i wanted the specific order. i used ($order->id == $find) in the blade to show that order in foreach. but Thanks for the help.